# How to sum digits if a input number while adding a power of nth to each digit corresponding to the formula given below?

Tags: java

I am having a hard time figuring out the solution to this problem. I am trying to develop a program in Java that takes a number as an input and prints the sum of power of each digit such that the power of nth digit is (n-1)th digit. However for the first digit, the power should be that of last digit. for example we have a input of 123 then the pattern should be 1^3 + 2^1 + 3^2. This has been confusing me and I would appreciate anyone's ideas.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int input;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        input = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(logic(input));
    }

    public static int logic(int input) {
        int sum = 0;
        while (input != 0) {
            sum = sum + input % 10;
            input = input / 10;
        }
        return sum
    }
}
```

This is all i got till now.

Formula is:

if input number is 123 then final result should be sum of:

```
1 ^ 3 + 2 ^ 1 + 3 ^ 2
```

Comment: What does your current implementation look like?

Comment: Currently i have just done till adding the digits but i dont know how to do the power thing.\

Comment: Show us the code.

Comment: `import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyTest {
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int input;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        input = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(logic(input));
    }
    
    public static int logic(int input){
      int sum = 0;
      while (input != 0){
        sum = sum + input % 10;
        input = input/10;
      }
      return sum
    }
}`

Comment: @YesB - [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62017507/edit) your question to post the code. Please make sure you post your current implementation when you post a new question to save the question from being closed.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just create an array of the individual digits and then do a for loop over that array?

Something like following:

```
int i =0;
while(n>0){
arr[i] = n%10;
n = n / 10;
i++;
}
```

Now in this case, arr[0] would actually be the unit digit and arr[1] would be the tens digit and so on.

So then you need to do:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i<arr.length-2; i++){
sum = sum + math.pow(arr[i], arr[i+1]);
}
// and finally 
sum = sum + math.pow(arr[arr.length-1], arr[0]);
```

Notice the last sum block, it raises the first digit in number from left to the power of last digit in number from right.

PS: I just wrote the pseudocode type format, you might need to fix the syntax.

Comment: The logic is flowed. You're raising first element of the array twice. It should be `math.pow(arr[arr.length-1], arr[0])` in the last line I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "";
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter the number: ");
            input = scanner.nextLine();
        } while (!input.matches("\\d+"));// Allow only positive int
        int num = Integer.parseInt(input);
        System.out.println(logic(num));
    }

    public static int logic(int input) {
        String[] digits = String.valueOf(input).split("");// Split on each digit
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
            int j = (i + 2) % digits.length;
            sum += Math.pow(Integer.parseInt(digits[i]), Integer.parseInt(digits[j]));
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter the number: 123
12
```

**[Update]:**

You can improve the performance of the function by parsing each digit into `int` and storing them into an `int[]`. Then, you can simply use the digits from this `int[]` instead of parsing the digits while calculating the power.

```
public static int logic(int input) {
    String[] arr = String.valueOf(input).split("");// Split on each digit
    int[] digits = new int[arr.length];

    // Fill digits[] with corresponding elements of arr[] parsed into int
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        digits[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
        int j = (i + 2) % digits.length;// The alternate index
        sum += Math.pow(digits[i], digits[j]);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

You can think of many more ways in which you can to do it and I recommend you try as many ways as you can do.

Answer (score 0):

I like short and concise code.

```java
int sum = 0;
Integer[] integers = Stream.of(Integer.toString(input).toCharArray())
  .map(String::valueOf)
  .map(Integer::parseInt)
  .toArray(Integer[]::new);
for (int i = 0 ; i < integers.length ; i++) {
  sum += i == 0 ? 
    Math.pow(integers[i], integers[integers.length - 1]) : 
    Math.pow(integers[i], integers[i - 1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
import static java.lang.Math.pow;
import java.util.Scanner;  
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number: ");
        int a = myObj.nextInt();;
        String number = String.valueOf(a);
        char[] digi = number.toCharArray();
        int n = String.valueOf(a).length();
        double sum = 0.0;int t = 1;
        double r =(double) (digi[0] - '0');
        double s =(double) (digi[n-1] - '0');
        sum += pow(r,s);       

        while(t<n)
        {
         double d = (double) (digi[t] - '0');
         double e = (double) (digi[t-1] - '0');
         sum += pow(d,e);t++;
        }

        int ans = (int) sum;
        System.out.print(ans);
    }
}
```

Your Input:

```
Enter number: 123                                                                                                                   
12
```

Test Case #1:

```
Enter number: 653                                                                                                                    
16084
```

Test Case #2:

```
Enter number: 7899                                                                                                                   
472917969
```